# How to move a div to the top of its parent on checkbox check?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

How can I make a `<div>` move to top within a parent `<div>`, based on a checked checkbox? I.e. if a checkbox of a row is checked, move the row to the top.

```js
$("#player-list input[type=checkbox].oncourt").live('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().prependTo("#player-list")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player-list">
    <div class="row">
        <div id=1><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=2><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=3><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=4><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=5><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=6><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=7><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=8><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `display: flex;` you can change the order of elements. So you can add and remove a class with `order: -1;` to your `row` to move it at the top of your list without modifying your DOM and that allows you to keep the original order easily

```js
$(document).on('change', '.oncourt', function() {
  if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {
$(this).closest('.row').addClass('is-checked');
  } else {
$(this).closest('.row').removeClass('is-checked');
  }
});
```

```css
#player-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.is-checked {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player-list">
    <div class="row">
        <div id=1><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=2><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=3><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=4><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=5><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=6><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=7><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id=8><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You took this further. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this).is(":checked")` to know whether a checkbox is checked. Here goes the full code.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#player-list input[type=checkbox].oncourt',function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
   $(this).parent().prependTo("#player-list");
    }else{
     $(this).parent().appendTo("#player-list")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player-list">

    <div class="row">
      <div id=1><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 1</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div id=2><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 2</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div id=3><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 3</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div id=4><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 4</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div id=5><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 5</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div id=6><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 6</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div id=7><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 7</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div id=8><input type="checkbox" class="oncourt"> ROW 8</div>
    </div>

</div>
```